# make api without making model and view in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am going to make an api in django which currently only return `hello world` when the url is hit. I am new to python and django and find a bit difficult to work in django because of working in PHP and its frameworks for a long time.

I have followed the tutorials but that takes me making the `models`, `templates`. but my requirement is simple. How can i achieve this. That when i hit the url of DJango app it return me the `hello world` or any json object in future.

Comment: You don't need to have a model, but you are going to need views in order to respond to requests.

Comment: so i just need a url route to that function in view? and then in that function return `\hello world`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define a view, that returns a HTTP response:

```
# app/views.py

from django.http import HttpResponse

def some_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('hello world')
```

and then you register your view in the `urls.py`:

```
# app/urls.py

from django.urls import url
from app.views import some_view

urlpatterns = [
    url('^my_url/$', some_view),
]
```

(given this is the root `urls.py` or there is at least some path to these URL patterns.

Then you can run the server, and access this page with `localhost:8000/my_url/` (or another URL given you configured it differently).

You can produce a JSON blob with:

```
# app/views.py

from django.http import JsonResponse

def some_view(request):
    return JsonResponse({'world': 'earth', 'status': 'hello'})
```

Comment: just let me test this and understand this will get back to you! actually very new to the django stuff :D

Comment: i have tested this and it works like a charm! i have only one question that i have to pass the parameters to the url like for now `http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_url/` is working fine but in future i have to make `http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_url/name='any name'` and i want to controll it in the view

Comment: @fatpotato: you can define a URL with *named groups* (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) to capture a value. But the above is rather "un-Django", a typical URL is `localhost:8000/my_url/any_name`. Or if it is a GET parameter, then you can use `request.GET` (then the URL is like `localhost:8000/my_url?name=any+name`.

Comment: actually i tried to use `http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_url/fatpotato` but it is giving me the 404 error.

Comment: @fatpotato: how did you define your `url(..)`?

Comment: `url('^my_url/$', some_view),`

Comment: @fatpotato: but as said in the linked documentation, you need to specify a named capture group, like `url(r'^my_url/(?P<username>\w+)/$, some_view)`, and change the view to `some_view(request, username): ...`.

Comment: sorry my bad did not see that

Comment: last question if the post method is required is there any thing i need to change?? or just get it from the request.POST? because according to [this django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#what-the-urlconf-searches-against) it does not require

Comment: @fatpotato: no, the POST data is stored in `request.POST`, and since POST parameters are not stored in the URI, you thus does not need to change the `urls.py`.

Comment: so i dont need to do anything with the url itself?

Comment: @fatpotato: not for a POST request, since the data of a POST is added to the HTTP request header. This is not specific to Django, this is how the HTTP protocol works.